# Regex searching using standard Windows executables

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I want to use regex matching from within a `.bat` file to validate console input.

Is there an `.exe` that comes with the standard windows installation that will help me do this?

ie something with a similar functionality to `grep` on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findstr`, it has some Regex functionality (but no *PCRE*, no *grep -o*). This is imo the only EXE with Regex support.
Syntax at [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).

Example:

```
findstr "pattern" "file"
echo %date%|findstr /e "[0-2]"  # true for 2012, false for 2013
```

There is a little help text on the command line: `findstr /?`.

Comment: You can put the input in a variable and send it with `echo` by the pipe to findstr, like `date` in my answer.

Comment: There are also some Batch/VBS hybrid scripts with more functionality in the net, [example here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27024#p27024).

Comment: Use the windows power shell which is an object oriented shell (pretty nice, I like it more than bash) and its "match" command. It also allows you to write "commandlets", shell scripts in C#.

Answer (score 0):

VB script can also [handle regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Let me Google that for you:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4310.powershell-working-with-regular-expressions-regex.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.11.powershell.aspx
- http://www.gfi.com/blog/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/

Last one is for shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Two tools - batch files - designed by regulars here which have regexp capability.

findrepl: - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

repl: - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855